# How to pass argument to useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have several buttons that when clicked call different APIs. My react App only uses Hooks and Context APIs. 
Before, it was as below:

```
      <button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={this.couchbaseCallApi('/couchbase/sync/initiate/sanity')}>Sync Sanity</button>
          <button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={this.couchbaseCallApi('/couchbase/sync/initiate/performance')}>Sync Performance</button>
          <button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={this.couchbaseCallApi('/couchbase/sync/initiate/endurance')}>Sync Endurance</button>
```

Where couchbaseCallApi function would use the fetch API to call the URL.

How can I pass these endpoints to a useEffect hook to call the correct endpoint?

Comment: Gonna need to see more code than that in order to help.
You shouldn't need useEffect to set endpoints. Since that doesn't sound like a side effect.

Answer (score -1):

My first recommendation is to use an existing solution like [React Query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query), a powerful query solution via Hooks.

I don't know if `useEffect` is the best method for performing asynchronous operations such as this but here's one potential solution. You want `useEffect` to re-run anytime the data it's querying changes, so that goes in its dependency list. You can use `useState` to trigger re-renders by changing the query value.

```
let [query, setQuery] = useState(null);
let [results, setResults] useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!query) return;

    let cancelled = false;

    // TODO: Perform query for sanity, performance, or endurance
    // This is an example using Promises, but callbacks also work
    couchbaseCallApi(query)
        .then((results) => {
            if (!cancelled) {
                setResults(results);
            }
        });

    // Cancel any on-going queries
    return () => {
        cancelled = true;
    }
}, [query]);
```

It should be noted that this only allows you to "sync" one thing at a time. If you want each sync (sanity, performance, endurance) to be their own query, then you would need a `useEffect` for each one of those, and the dependency list would need to change (I recommend a timestamp).

To trigger an api call you would just update query:

```
<button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={() => setQuery('/couchbase/sync/initiate/sanity')}>Sync Sanity</button>
<button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={() => setQuery('/couchbase/sync/initiate/performance')}>Sync Performance</button>
<button class="btn margin-1-lr" onClick={() => setQuery('/couchbase/sync/initiate/endurance')}>Sync Endurance</button>
```